# Time from creation to closed

Tags: jira, average, confluence

I am trying to calculate the average time for all the jira cases that are created and until they are resolved.

How can this be done, for a specific project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont say how you want to calculate this.

The simplest way is to add the [Resolution Time Gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/adding-the-resolution-time-gadget-185729506.html) to your dashboard. Here you can add a filter to specify which issues you want to consider.

This will give you a nice bar chart of the average resolution times of issues over a given period

If you want more control, you can write a script for it with the Jira REST API

If you create a jql for the issues you are interested in, you can call the REST api with a url like this:

```
https://jira.intern.sparebank1.no/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=e6462u
```

This will return a whole bunch of info, but you are most interested in the issues array elements, and specifically the fields "created" and "resolutiondate"

A snipped version of the JSON returned is:

```
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
      "id": "104799",
      "self": "https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/104799",
      "key": "HELLO-1",
      "fields": {
        ...
        "resolutiondate": "2015-06-25T09:12:27.000+0200",
        "created": "2015-03-18T16:18:38.000+0100"
       ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can calculate the difference between the two for each issue element and find an average.

More info on Jira REST API: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

A blog I wrote on how to script stuff like this (and present in a graph in confluence ;) ): http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html